# Updation operation not working in PHP throwing undefined index error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am performing some Crud operations  without refreshing page in PHP.
All the operations work except for update,it gives me a dialog box showing an **error of undefined index id and showing me the final result   "Data Updated"**. But this updation does not remain on screen when the page is refreshed nor it is seen in my database.I get my previous data as it is. 
Please help me fix this.

Below is the code-
   This is my main page :

```
function edit_data(id,text,column_name)
        {
        $.ajax({
            url:"update.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
        });
        }
```

I have used **blur**  event for updation.

```
$(document).on('blur','.name',function(){
    var id= $(this).data("id1");
    var name=$(this).text();
    edit_data(id,name,"name");
    });

    $(document).on('blur','.lname',function(){
    var id= $(this).data("id2");
    var lname=$(this).text();
    edit_data(id,lname,"lname");
    });
```

select.php

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $output .='
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
    <td class="name" data-id1"'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row["name"].'</td>
    <td class="lname" data-id2"'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row["lname"].'</td>
    <tr/>';
    }
```

update.php    I get error for this page

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db2017",$link);

$id=$_POST["id"];  //Undefined index "id"
$text=$_POST["text"];
$column_name=$_POST["column_name"];
$sql="update detail set ".$column_name."='".$text."' where id='".$id."' ";

if(mysql_query($sql))
{

    echo "Data Updated";

}
?>
```

Kindly ignore the use of mysql_query instead of mysqli_query. The function is not working on my browser hence switched to mysql-query().
Also I tried `if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }` according to previous answers on Stackoverflow. Doesn't work!!

Comment: The reason you use `mysqli` over `mysql_` is for the parameterized queries functionality which closes the SQL injection hole. That could be the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data id in your html markup didnt have `=` assignment operator :

```
<td class="name" data-id1"'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row["name"].'</td>
<td class="lname" data-id2"'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row["lname"].'</td>
```

Should be :

```
<td class="name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row["name"].'</td>
<td class="lname" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row["lname"].'</td>
```

End up, this below code will always got undefined data :

```
var id= $(this).data("id1"); // undefined
var id= $(this).data("id2"); // undefined
```

When the data is `undefined`, the `data` you send using ajax request will skip `id` property if the value is undefined :

```
data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},
```

When the request reach the server side endpoint, it will look at the `$_POST["id"]`, but POST data not having an index with the name `id`, ends up you got the errors `undefined index`